# My unity pannel on cairo dock doesnt work

Tags: unity, themes, mac, dock, cairo

I just upgraded my Ubuntu to 13.04 and installed mac theme from Noobslab and installed Cairo Dock. The problem is when I log in I only find Cairo Gnome and I need Cairo Unity Pannel.
Please Respond,
 Micro

Answer (score 0):

There is no more cairo+unity panel, because now the top panel can't be used outside of Unity.
A possible solution: make another dock at the top and place there the usual applets (clock, Indicators, logout, etc)